# Удалить дубликаты в массиве без использования коллекций. Java

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, циклы

Необходимо удалить дубликаты в массиве без использования коллекций.

C `ArrayList` или `HashSet` все понятно, тут делать не чего, но мне задание дали удалить дубликаты не используя ничего, кроме массивов. При чем метод должен работать, даже если дубликатов больше двух.

- Исходный массив {1 ,1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3}
- Искомый результат {1, 2, 3}

В общем уже голову сломал, может кто поможет?

Спасибо.

Comment: Отсортировать массив, посчитать уникальные числа, выделить новый массив, пересыпать из старого в новый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я полагаю, ваше задание на использование циклов при работе с массивами. Если так, то прямолинейный подход с использованием циклов может выглядеть следующим образом

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3 };

        int n = a.length;

        for ( int i = 0, m = 0; i != n; i++, n = m )
        {
            for ( int j = m = i + 1; j != n; j++ )
            {
                if ( a[j] != a[i] )
                {
                    if ( m != j ) a[m] = a[j];
                    m++;
                }
            }
        }


        if ( n != a.length )
        {
            int[] b = new int[n];
            for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) b[i] = a[i];

            a = b;
        }

        for ( int x : a ) System.out.print( x + " " );
        System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Вывод программы

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: Да это правда очень похоже на то как я решил только на много более коротко. Спасибо большое! У меня просто крыша едет когда несколько циклов а потом еще несколько ифов внутри. Надо как-то тренероваться )))  А зачем вы Exception в сигнатуре пробрасываете разве здесь есть методы которые этого требуют?

Comment: @Павел Я использовал on-line компилятор на www.ideone.com, где уже задано объявление main.

Comment: @Павел Я подправил код. Смотрите мой обновленный ответ. В случае если массив уже упорядочен, то не надо создавать промежуточный массив.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] a = new int[] {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3};
int[] b = new int[a.length];
int curIndex = 0;
for (int i: a) {
    if (!IntStream.range(0, curIndex).anyMatch(num - > b[num] == i)) {
        b[curIndex++] = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(b, curIndex))); //[1, 2, 3]
```

**UPDATE**

```
!IntStream.range(0, b.length).anyMatch(num - > b[num] == i)
```

можно заменить следующим методом

```
public static boolean contains(int[] a, int num) {
    for (int i in a) {
        if (i == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

И тогда основной for будет следующим

```
for (int i: a) {
    if (!contains(b, i))) {
        b[curIndex++] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: @zRrr резонно, благодарю

Comment: Это круто! а вот это место не понятно !IntStream.range(0, curIndex).anyMatch(num - > b[num] == i)

Comment: Это механизм Stream из java8. Данная конструкция создает интовый стрим по заданому промежутку, и мы смотрим, что у нас все соответствуют переданному условию

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
public void tt(){
    testArray(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,5,5});
    testArray(new int[]{11,12,16,1,2,3,4});
    testArray(new int[]{3,3,3,3,3,3,3});
    testArray(new int[]{1});
    testArray(new int[]{});
    testArray(new int[]{10,11,11,11,11,11,11});
    testArray(new int[]{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4});
}

public void testArray(int[] a){
    Arrays.sort(a);
    a = removeDuplicates(a);
    Arrays.stream(a).forEach(value -> System.out.print(value + " "));
    System.out.println();
}

public int[] removeDuplicates(int[] array){
    //Частные случаи
    if(array.length == 1) return array;
    if(array.length == 0) return new int[0];
    //
    //Размер больше 1, уникальное значение как минимум одно
    int unique = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] != array[i - 1]){
            unique++; //Если текущий с предыдущим не равны - значит
                      // увеличиваем счетчик уникальных значений
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[unique]; //Новый массив нужного размера
    int k = 0; //Текущая позиция в новом массиве
    if(result.length > 0){
        result[k++] = array[0]; //Пишем в новый массив первое уникальное значение
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] != array[i - 1]){
            result[k++] = array[i]; //Пишем в новый массив остальные уникальные значения
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Запустите свой тест для такого массива {1,2,3,1,2,3}

Comment: @AndrewBystrow, запустил, всё корректно.

Comment: У вас счетчик уникальных элементов для данного массива ,когда считается, будет равен 6,а не 3м

Comment: @AndrewBystrow, нет, не будет... Я массив предварительно сортирую...

Comment: Хотя да, прошу прощения за невнимательность

Answer (score 1):

```
public void noDubs(){
    for (int i = 0; i<nElems; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<nElems; j++)
            if(i!=j) {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {         
                    for (int k = j; k < nElems; k++)    // move higher ones down
                        a[k] = a[k + 1];
                    nElems--;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.ddd;
class Solution {
    private int[] sortArrays(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                    int tos = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = tos;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    private int countNotNullElements(int[] arr){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] != 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public void singleNumber(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if(nums[i] == nums[j]){
                    nums[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        sortArrays(nums);
        int size = countNotNullElements(nums);
        int Array[] = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Array[i] = nums[i];
            System.out.println(Array[i]);
        }
    }
}
    class ddd {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Solution r = new Solution();
            int[] arr = {2,7,7,7,11,11,11,15};
            r.singleNumber(arr);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сдал. Завтра узнаем что мне педагог скажет вот такой вариант получился. Шапками не кидать, я второй месяц занимаюсь. Всем большое спасибо за помощь, особенно простые примеры навели на конструктивные мысли.

```
public class DuplicateWithoutCollection {

int nulls;

/**
 * Объединяет три метода.
 * @see #addNullInsteadDuplicate Добавление null вместо дкбликатов
 * @see #bubbleForNull(String[]) Сортировка null в конец массива
 * @see #deleteNulls(String[]) Перезапись всех null в новый массив
 * <p>
 *     Тест:
 * @see DuplicateWithoutCollectionTest#WhenArrayWithDuplicatesInThenArrayWithoutDuplicatesOut()
 */
public String[] finishDeleteDuplicate(String[] arr) {
    String[] addNull = addNullInsteadDuplicate(arr);
    String[] bubble = bubbleForNull(addNull);
    String[] deleteNull = deleteNulls(bubble);
    return deleteNull;
}

/**
 * Заменяет дубликаты на null
 * Записывает колличество нулей в переменну nulls
 * <p>
 *     Тест
 * @see DuplicateWithoutCollectionTest#WhenArrayWithDuplicateInThenArrayWithNullInsteadDupliateOut()
 */
public String[] addNullInsteadDuplicate(String[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] != null && arr[j] != null && arr[i].equals(arr[j])) {
                arr[j] = null;
                nulls++;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

/***
 * Выталкиват null в конец массива.
 * <p>
 *     Тест
 * @see DuplicateWithoutCollectionTest#WhenArrayWithNullInThenAllNullsGoToTheEndArray()
 */
public String[] bubbleForNull(String[] arr) {
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == null) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

/**
 * Удаляет нули.
 * <p>
 *     Тест
 * @see DuplicateWithoutCollectionTest#WhenArrayWithNullInThenArrayWithoutNullOut()
 * */
public String[] deleteNulls(String[] arr) {
    String[] result = new String[arr.length - this.nulls];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

}