# Удалить дубликаты из массива без использования Set и библиотечных методов

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

```java
public static void printWordsRev(String s) {

}
```

Ниже приведён пример входных и выходных данных.

Входные данные: "***money honey happy*** money honey money happy money happy".

Выходные данные: "***money honey happy***".

Можно использовать только `ArrayList`, без `Set`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удалить дубликаты в массиве без использования коллекций. Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580198/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-java)

Comment: И пожалуйста, пользуйтесь поиском по сайту, прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: Так `ArrayList` -- вполне себе "библиотечный" класс и методы у него такие же.  Выходит, что его библиотечными методами можно пользоваться?

Answer (score 2):

Если можно использовать "библиотечные" методы интерфейса `List`, то для этой задачи можно предложить несколько решений.  Также стоит сделать общие методы для получения списка слов из строки и печати списка строк.

1. Вложенные циклы с удалением всех дубликатов после данного слова
   Для каждого i-го слова проверяем все оставшиеся слова и удаляем дубликаты:```

```java
private static List<String> getWords(String str) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+")));
}

private static void print(List<String> words) {
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", words));
}

public static void printWordsRevFor1(String s) {
    List<String> words = getWords(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        String w = words.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.size(); j++) {
            if (w.equals(words.get(j))) {
                words.remove(j--); // коррекция индекса после удаления
            }
        }
    }
    print(words);    
}
```

1a. Удаление дубликатов в конце списка

```java
public static void printWordsRev1a(String s) {
    List<String> words = getWords(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        String w = words.get(i);
        for (int j = words.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
            if (w.equals(words.get(j))) {
                words.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    
    print(words);
}
```

2. Установка дубликатов в `null` с последующим удалением при помощи `List::removeIf`

```java
public static void printWordsRev2(String s) {
    List<String> words = getWords(s);
    for (int i = 0, n = words.size(); i < n; i++) {
        String w = words.get(i);
        if (w == null) continue; // пропустить уже найденный дубликат
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (w.equals(words.get(j))) {
                words.set(j, null);
            }
        }
    }
    words.removeIf(w -> null == w);
    
    print(words);
}
```

3. Поиск дубликатов с конца массива с помощью `List::lastIndexOf`

```java
public static void printWordsRev3(String s) {
    List<String> words = getWords(s);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        String w = words.get(i);
        int j;
        while ((j = words.lastIndexOf(w)) != i) {
            words.remove(j);
        }
    }
    
    print(words);
}
```

4. "Читерское" использование `List::stream`:

```java
public static void printWordsRev4(String s) {
    print(getWords(s).stream().distinct().toList());
}
```

---

Ещё пара способов:
5. Удаление дубликатов при помощи `List::subList` + `List.removeIf`:
Известно, что [`List::subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) не создаёт новый список, а является представлением текущего списка, соответственно, изменения в подсписке, полученном таким образом, будут применяться и к начальному списку.

```java
public static void printWordsRev5(String s) {
    List<String> words = getWords(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        String w = words.get(i);
        words.subList(i + 1, words.size()).removeIf(w::equals);
    }
    
    print(words);
}
```

6. Использование итератора `ListIterator` + `List::indexOf` для удаления в конце списка

```java
public static void printWordsRev6(String s) {
    //print(getWords(s).stream().distinct().toList());
    List<String> words = getWords(s);

    // итератор списка с конца
    ListIterator<String> it = words.listIterator(words.size());
    
    while (it.hasPrevious()) {
        String tail = it.previous();
        int ix = it.previousIndex() + 1;
        if (ix > words.indexOf(tail)) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }

    print(words);
}
```