# Создать новый список из исходного , который должен состоять из неповторяющихся чисел изначального списка

Tags: java

Дан список целых чисел. Создать новый список, содержащий неповторяющиеся
значения из исходного списка.
Например изначальный список: 2 2 3 2 3 4 6 7 9 7
новый список: 4 6 9
Как это можно реализовать ?
Вот метод , который у меня получился, но он делает вообще что-то не то

```
public static List<Integer> createNewList(List<Integer> list) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(list.get(0)); 
        for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++)
            if(list.get(i) != list.get(i-1)){
                result.add(list.get(i));
            }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Доброго времени суток. Предоставьте свои попытки решения данной проблемы, иначе Вам вряд ли окажут помощь в Вашем вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Похожая задача: [Получить из строки только уникальные элементы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359329/)

Стандартное быстрое решение задач такого рода: вычислить мапу частот для каждого элемента во входном списке; отфильтровать по значениям частоты 1; сформировать список из оставшихся ключей.

Решение со Stream API:

```java
public static<T> List<T> getUniqueElementsStream(List<T> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            x -> x,
            LinkedHashMap::new, // Обеспечить порядок вставки как в исходном списке
            Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1) // или Collectors.counting()
        ))  // Map<T, Integer>
        .entrySet()
        .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<T, Integer>>
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Решение с циклами, `Map::merge`, `Collection::removeIf` (цикл можно заменить на `list.forEach(item -> freq.merge(item, 1, Integer::sum))`:

```java
public static<T> List<T> getUniqueElementsFor(List<T> list) {
    Map<T, Integer> freq = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    // list.forEach(item -> freq.merge(item, 1, Integer::sum)); // вариант вместо цикла 
    for (T item : list) {
        freq.merge(item, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    freq.values().removeIf(v -> v != 1); // удалить все неуникальные элементы
    return new ArrayList<>(freq.keySet());
}
```

---

Решение с использованием двух сетов и удалением дубликатов.
Основано на том, что метод `Set::add` возвращает `false`, если не произошло изменение сета, то есть обнаружен дубликат элемента:

```java
public static<T> List<T> getUniqueElementsSet(List<T> list) {
    Set<T> ones = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Set<T> dups = new HashSet<>();
    for (T item : list) {
        if (!ones.add(item)) {
            dups.add(item); // найден дубликат
        }
    }
    ones.removeAll(dups); // удалить все неуникальные элементы

    return new ArrayList<>(ones);
}
```

В вышеуказанных примерах входной список не изменяется, а создаётся новый список без дубликатов.

---

Если по какой-то причине нельзя пользоваться вычислением частот / множествами `Set` для обнаружения дубликатов, а только лишь "стандартными" методами, доступными для списков, то недавно была похожая задача: [Удалить дубликаты из массива без использования `Set` и библиотечных методов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1502628/), решения из которой нужно слегка модифицировать, чтобы удалить также элемент, для которого обнаружены дубликаты.  В частности, придется создать копию входного списка, модифицировать её и вернуть как результат:

- Решение с обычным циклом `for`

```java
public static<T> List<T> keepUniques1(List<T> input) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        T item = list.get(i);
        boolean dupFound = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (Objects.equals(item, list.get(j))) {
                list.remove(j--); // коррекция индекса после удаления
                dupFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (dupFound) {
            list.remove(i--);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

- Решение с использованием подсписков:

```java
public static<T> List<T> keepUniques2(List<T> input) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        T item = list.get(i);
        if (list.subList(i + 1, list.size()).removeIf(curr -> Objects.equals(item, curr))) {
            list.remove(i--);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Достаточно просто создать **Map**(ключ - число, значение - количество вхождений) и потом пройтись по массиву, проверяя количество вхождений в нашей **Map**:

```java
    private static List<Integer> createNewList(List<Integer> list) {
        //Создаём Map, подсчитывая количества вхождений чисел массива
        Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
        list.forEach((item) -> counts.put(item, counts.get(item) == null ? 1 : counts.get(item) + 1));
        //Возвращаем List, где value() в нашей Map = 1
        return list.stream()
                .filter(item -> counts.get(item) == 1)
                .toList();
    }
```

Comment: Логика решения интересная.  Однако вместо нескольких вызовов `Map::put`/`Map::get` лучше использовать `Map::merge` как показано в моем ответе или хотя бы `Map::compute`: `list.forEach(item -> counts.compute(item, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1))`

Comment: Или же вариант `list.forEach(item -> counts.put(item, 1 + freq.getOrDefault(item, 0)));` -- но в целом вариант с `merge` самый лаконичный

Comment: @NowhereMan Да, с `merge` будет лаконичнее. Спасибо, что поправили.